# MeshLab: Can I export quality histogram to external file?

Tags: histogram, meshlab

Using MeshLab I get quality histogram of distances after applying Hausdorff distance between two mashes. I want to export the histogram to external file so I can analysis the histogram in external tool like python or MATLAB.
Can I do it? How?
Thanks
Niv

Comment: Please share your code with us so we may find you solution for your particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easy if you use the filter "Distance from reference mesh" instead of "Hausdorff Distance". That filter will leave the distances stored as quality value on each vertex of the Measured mesh.

After that, you can save the mesh to plot the distances outside of meshlab. The recommended file format is PLY, and ensure "Quality" checkbox **is** checked and "Binary encoding" **is not** checked.
The output file has a 11 lines header and then a line per each vertex containing  4 numbers. First 3 numbers are the XYZ coordinates, and the last value is the quality (which is the distance you are looking for your plot)

```
0 -2 0 1.902114 
0 2 0 1.902113 
1 -2 0 1.701302 
0.9848077 -2 0.1736482 1.714225 
0.9396926 -2 0.3420202 1.722303
```

This method works not only with distances, but also with any value that meshlab can store as quality : curvature, distance to boundary, etc..